# Change PHP Url (prestashop)

Tags: php, url, prestashop

I want to change a url. I have a table that contains a product id and a reference id. I have to create a p.php file that allows (from a Prestashop project) to write in the url website_name/p.php?refId=123456 and when we send it in the search bar, we get the product page corresponding to the product id (a product id corresponds to a reference id). Do you have any leads? I know I have to use DBQuery and require this file

```
require dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php';
```

Is anyone has a suggestion please ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

By requiring:

```
require dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php';
```

in your script you are bootstrapping Prestashop core , so you can start using the [DB class](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/components/database/db/)

immediatly in your PHP script to manually retrieve your data, or (preferred) just use the built-in Prestashop methods like **Product::getIdByReference()** to retrieve an ID product and then instantiate a Product object with

```
  $prod = new Product($id);
```

and extract your details from there.

Comment: Thank you for you response, may you be more precise ?

Comment: I think I've provided all you need to start coding :) You can explore devdocs and PS classes to figure out native methods.